# Change items in a <select> onchange of another <select> element

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-select

So basically I have 2 `<select>` elements, and what I want is that the user selects a option in the first `<select>` and then the second `<select>` changes its options depending on what is selected. The second `<select>` is empty, and when the first`<select>` get changed it needs to add `<options>` to the second `<select>`.

HTML 1st select :

```
<select name="roof_width" onChange="getWidth(this.selectedIndex)" value="3" class="content_selectinput" id="select_width">
    <?php
        $i = 0;
        $x = 2;
        while(isset($dak_breedte[$i]))
        {
            if(isset($roof_width_index) && $roof_width_index == $i)
            {
                echo"<option value='$i' id='$i' selected='Selected'>".$dak_breedte[$i]." Meter </option>";
                $i++;
            }                   
            else
            {
                echo"<option value='$x'>".$dak_breedte[$i]." Meter</option>";
                $i++;
            }
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

HTML 2nd select :

```
<select name="NokBreedte" onClick="ridgeCheck()" value="3" class="content_selectinput" id="select_ridge" >
</select>
```

JavaScript :

```
function getWidth(index)
{
    ridge_min = index - 10;
    ridge_max = index + 10
    ridge_select = document.getElementById("select_ridge");
    for(i = 0; i <= 99; i++)
    {
        if(i < ridge_min || i > ridge_max)
        {
            ridge_select.add(ridge_values[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

The text values for the second `<select>` are stored in an array. I searched the web for a while and also tried it with jQuery, but nothing works.

To be clear, what I need is :

When a user changes the first `<select>` the second `<select>` needs to change directly.

Comment: Shouldn't `ridge_select.add(ridge_values[i]);` be `select_ridge.add(ridge_values[i]);`??

Comment: I don't think so, since i declare ridge_select as the select element. I could be wrong though, but I thought this would work.

Comment: Yeah... I didn't see that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using jquery replace your function with this one

```
function getWidth(){
    var index = $('#select_width').val();
    ridge_min = index - 10;
    ridge_max = index + 10

    var options = '';


    for(i = 0; i <= 99; i++)
    {
        if(i > ridge_min || i < ridge_max)
        {
            options += "<option>" + ridge_values[i] + "</option>";
        }
     }

     $('#select_ridge').html(options);
}
```

Also change

```
getWidth(this.selectedIndex)
```

to

```
getWidth()
```

Update

Sorry modified again but you have used the following condition wrong.

```
if(i < ridge_min || i > ridge_max)
```

should be

```
if(i > ridge_min || i < ridge_max)
```

Comment: It adds 99 <options> instead of only the options between ridge_min & ridge_max.... , I did was able to add stuff so thanks for that!

Comment: I tried 'em both, including changing the || with && but using a document.write I saw that he loops the if 99 times....

Comment: using alerts I noticed, he sees index as "2" no matter what i've selected, ridge_min is -8 and ridge_max is 210.... any idea what i've done wrong?

Comment: I changed 1 variable to get index and ridge_min to a good int, also i used parseInt(index)+10 on ridge_max, it works now! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to delete all old values (all code you should use in onChange's function)

```
//Clear the HTML Select DropdownList
$('#select_ridge option').empty();
```

});

after you need to add new values

```
    var listvalues= new Array();    
    listvalues[0] = { Text: "val1", Value: "1" };
    listvalues[1] = { Text: "val2", Value: "2" };    
    listvalues[2] = { Text: "val3", Value: "3" };    

    $.each(listvalues, function (index) {            
            $("#select_ridge").append(GetOption(listvalues[index].Text, listvalues[index].Value));        
            });    
    });    
    function GetOption(text, value) {        
            return "<option value = '" + value + "'>" + text + "</option>"    
    }
```

Comment: Not completely sure but I think the `.remove()` doesn't work as you expect. To delete the options contained by the select, you need to call `.empty()`